# Why is there a need for a "be"?

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

I listened to a sentence from an IELTS listening

> What else should managers be looking for?

Why is there a need for a "be"?

> What else should managers looking for?

Is it not right?

Comment: Modal verbs like *should* require **infinitive** complements: you can say "What else should managers look for?", but not "What else should managers looking for?"

Answer (score 1):

> What else should managers looking for?

This proposition that you made is ungrammatical as there's no a main verb (bare infinitive) to act as a complement of the modal should.

Consequently, to be grammatical, the sentence should be either like your first scenario:

> What else should managers be looking for?

or, as StoneyB points out in his comment:

> What else should managers look for?